# how PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer load properties files?

Tags: java, spring

I have doubt related to PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. Below are my configuration in application-context.xml file. According to documents it will look into {user.home}/conf directory first for application.properties. If not present then it will load from classpath which is true.

Now i have one question if one key value is not present inside {user.home}/conf directory's application.properties file, however it is there in classpath's application.properties. So How it will identify and load that key value?

sorry for lengthy explanation.

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
                <value>file:///${user.home}/conf/application.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
```

Comment: If both .properties are available, all the keys are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is no possibility to get that placeholder solved, because the same class that you are instantiating is the one in charge to resolve the properties. In this case ${user.home} is not going to be solved, by that reason ${user.home}/conf/application.properties will not be reached as a valid location.

Answer (score 0):

It will not work if the property is not present, you can extend this class PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and use the bean that you are used to extend the class, in that way you can manage from where are loaded the properties and have the control of all the exceptions.